# How to use Rest service class as a library class

Tags: spring, rest, import

I have a Spring app and I created a Rest service with a couple of GET methods.
Now that web service needs to be moved to a library module to be used by other modules. How can I do that? Where to place it in the project I want to use it? Extend it in the project? I don't have anything to add to it or override (it is a kind of utility web service). I just need its name as a component. Would I just have some child class that is just extending it with empty body and give it a component name? Is that ok?

```
import xxx.yyy.lib.UtilityWebService;
@Component("utilityWS")
public class MyWebService extends UtilityWebService{
}
```

What would be the best practice for this situation?

Comment: why are you  not calling this rest service from other module? you can simply hit the url.

Comment: The service is not called explicitly, it is handler for errror codes in web.xml. That is why moving it to lib seems tricky, or it is not?

Comment: still no need to put code in the lib. just mention rest url for the error codes in web.xml.

Comment: Yes, but requirement is for code that handles errors to go to lib so the handlers can be reused.